# Dateutil & Pytz missing dependencies - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to run a code for portfolio optimization and i get the following error right on import of pandas.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/***/Desktop/Markowitz-master/MarkowitzOpt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas import Series, DataFrame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['pytz', 'dateutil']
```

I used pip freeze to check all installed packages, and both puts and dateutil are installed.

Any insights would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you running multiple versions of Python, or do you have a custom pip configuration for installing packages in a non-standard location?

Comment: Actually im using Python 2.7 and thats about it... and im using standard pip configuration to install the packages in the standard location

Comment: I notice someone had a similar issue, confusing dateutil with python-dateutil. Try "pip install python-dateutil pytz --force-reinstall --upgrade"

Comment: @benjamin thanks a lot !! that solved it!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it, I'll add my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

dateutil can get confused with python-dateutil, try the following:

```
pip install python-dateutil pytz --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are also using conda you may have to also update the packages in conda.

`conda update python-dateutil pytz`

This worked for me.

*Note*: I was getting the error when I attempted to load pandas in IPython for Python 2.7.15. I was *not* in a conda virtual env but the ipython install that was being loaded came from conda. Updating the packages in conda solved the issue.